# programmatically exclude new fields from render()

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I need to render a limited number of fields from a given content type, without exposing the new ones I may add some day in the future.

Now I have:

`print render($page)`

When a new field is added to the content type, I have that added to the render($page) as well. I don't want this to happen.
Aside hiding the field from "admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/display", how can I programmatically exclude new fields from render.

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to use [hide() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/hide/8.5.x) in a preprocess hook as:

```
hide($page['field_machine_name']);
```

Comment: I don't  know the field name I will add tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is not render out all of $page. So you could get rid of:

```
print render($page)
```

And instead just render the elements within it you want e.g. :

```
print render($page['field_my_field']);
```

That will mean no matter what other fields you add in the future only the ones you specifically render in your template will be shown

Comment: This would imply a parcial  CSS rewrite, already tested.